# Differentiation and Integration - Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

My textbook says it is the connection between differentiation and integration, but I don't see how that's the case since we're only integrating.

It states, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and if $F$ is any anti-derivative of $f$ on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$.

Would someone please explain the link between the two.

Thanks

Comment: So, you see how derivatives are mentioned when defining $F$?  That's the link.

Comment: $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$ **iff** $F' = f$.

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a real answer to expand my comment.  There are two fundamental theorems, which I'll state under slightly restrictive conditions so that they look the same.

1. Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval and $F$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose derivative $F'$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]$.  Then we have
   $$\int_a^b F'(x) \, dx = F(b) - F(a).$$
2. Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval and let $f$ be function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on $[a,b]$.  Then the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and
   $$F'(x) = f(x).$$

The first one says that "the integral of the derivative is the original function" and the second one says that "the derivative of the integral is the original function".  So, differentiation and integration are "inverse" operations (in quotes because the first statement is sort of a lie; the integral differs from the original function by a constant).

Answer (score 0):

Recall the first part of the fundamental theorem.

Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Define (I think this is key), the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(x)\, dx$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Moreover, $f=F'$.

As someone in the comments said, we define $F$ such that $f$ is the derivative of $F$. I think that may be the link you are looking for.